# How to retrieve all rows that contain multiple categories in postgres?

Tags: database, postgresql

I think I am close with this query, but I need help getting it over the line. What I want to do is pretty simple. I need to return a list of courses that have both of these two particular categories - COURSE_CURRENT and COURSE_ENDED. A course should only have one of these categories.The reason is that they are displayed in a particular tab dependent on the category. The problem is some courses have both of them and they are not displaying.

If the query checks for the course Id that is commented out, we get two rows. One each for the two categories, which is correct. I need to be able to do this for all courses that have both categories.

**SAMPLE DATA**

- "TheGreatestCourse_4012" "The Greatest Course 4012"  "COURSE_ENDED"
- "TheGreatestCourse_4012" "The Greatest Course 4012"  "COURSE_CURRENT"

Here is my query

```
select cm.course_id, cm.course_name, gc.batch_uid
from course_main cm
inner join gateway_course_categories gcc on gcc.crsmain_pk1 = cm.pk1
inner join gateway_categories gc on gc.pk1 = gcc.gatewaycat_pk1
--where cm.course_id = 'TheGreatestCourse_4012'
where (gc.batch_uid = 'COURSE_CURRENT' or gc.batch_uid = 'COURSE_ENDED')
group by cm.course_id,cm.course_name,gc.batch_uid
HAVING COUNT(gc.batch_uid) > 1
order by course_id
```

Any help is appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution. I needed to add a count to the batch_uid.

```
select COUNT(gc.batch_uid) as countBatch, cm.course_id, cm.course_name
from course_main cm
inner join gateway_course_categories gcc on gcc.crsmain_pk1 = cm.pk1
inner join gateway_categories gc on gc.pk1 = gcc.gatewaycat_pk1
where (gc.batch_uid = 'COURSE_CURRENT' or gc.batch_uid = 'COURSE_ENDED')
group by cm.course_id,cm.course_name
HAVING COUNT(gc.batch_uid) > 1
order by course_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `LIKE`

```
where (gc.batch_uid LIKE '%COURSE_CURRENT%' or gc.batch_uid LIKE '%COURSE_ENDED%')
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, but this didn't work. No rows were returned